# How to attach eye hooks to glass fish tank to support a lightweight light fixture?

Tags: troubleshooting, glass, design

I have a 30" fishtank that, due to the filter setup, requires a light bar that doesn't stretch the entire tank. I have a wooden dowel that fits well inside two eye hooks; the dowel will serve as the support for one side of the light while the other will rest on the tank edge. How can I connect the eye hook to the tank? I'm thinking there must be a type of clamp that allows an eye hook to screw in, but have not found one. [image: this is how I'm imagining it might fit together]

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a home improvement question as defined by this network. Voting to close.

Comment: why don't you just lay the dowel across the top of the tank?

Answer (score 1):

Take a piece of wood and cut a notch in it the width of the tank edge. Then screw the eye hook into it and you can then sit this on the edge.

Comment: My thought as well, except I'd forego the eye screw and put a hole in the block.